# Places to Find Rock Climbing Ball Holds

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing

What are some places to purchase rock climbing ball holds like the ones on [Atomik Climbing Holds](http://www.atomikclimbingholds.com/bombs) and [Three Ball Climbing](http://www.threeballclimbing.com/6-inch-ninja-beast-balls.htm)?

I'm looking to build something similar to cannonball alley on American Ninja Warrior as cheap as possible. I'm considering just making them myself but was wondering if there is anywhere to get them cheaper than those sites. I'm not asking for specific advertisements/promotions, but simply all the places to get those types of rock climbing holds.

Comment: Hi etangins. I'm sorry but shopping advice is off topic (in general on SE sites actually) on TGO. You could maybe rephrase your question? As it stands this is likely to get closed.

Comment: How would I best rephrase it? See I'm not really looking for recommendations or advertisements, but simply if such services exist. Put simply, I would like to get those rock climbing holds and need the best way to obtain them.

Comment: I posted an answer, hopefully it helps! As @Liam mentioned, shopping advice is generally off-topic. That said, if you want other options, now you have it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than give you shopping advice, you can visit [DPM's climbing hold review page](http://www.dpmclimbing.com/climbing-gear/view/climbing-hold-review), where they list and review more hold manufacturers than you probably knew existed. You could start there if you wanted more options, but I've personally shopped around in the past for holds and I can promise you that they are all very comparable.

Since you already know some places though, and have indicated that you would prefer something cheaper, I'll go with the assumption that you might end up jerry rigging something together yourself.

This is likely going to mean some work on your part. The easiest is buying some wooden spheres from a craft store like the ones below, and rigging a big fat eye bolt to them. Etsy is a great place for craft supplies if needed, but there are many other places also.

[image: Wooden Spheres for Sale]

[image: Eye Bolt Examples]

---

Most often, climbing holds are made with a grainy textured finish, making them easier to grip for us mortals. If you chose the DIY path, I'd also suggest asking at your local home-depot for a varnish/finish that will achieve a similar result.

[image: Textured Deck Paint]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give a useful and effective answer that points me in the right direction. That's what I was looking for. I didn't see other sphere holds on any sites but the wooden spheres is a good idea.

Comment: Etsy seems to only have tiny sphered, around 1" in diameter. Are there any places with larger spheres like wherever you got the image from? I'm trying to do a little looking around.